# I want deploy my react js site in firebase. But I Found this error. How can I fixed it?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

**Firebase error message is:**

Error: Task 1571sa4d6... failed: retries
exhausted after 6 attempts, with error: Failed to make request to https://upload-firebasehosting.googleapis.com/upload/sites/...

Answer (score 0):

Reasons can be

1. Remove **.firebase** folder and try to redeploy , maybe it can help you
2. Your internet connection is slow and project size is bigger